# .net Channels : Why producer output is consumed serially one after the other by the consumer/reader in an unbounded channel

Tags: c#, .net, task, channel

Main program starts a task which is consumer task for Channel. Consumer task code is :

```
while (await channelReader.WaitToReadAsync())
            {
                while(channelReader.TryRead(out item))
                {
                    console.writeline("item is"+item.clientId);
                }
            }
```

There is socket server. When socket client connects to server, server starts task for each client. Each client task is a producer for the channel.
producer code is:

```
foreach (var item in itemList )
{
     item.clientId = clientId;        
     await drawChannelWriter.WriteAsync(item);
}
```

What happens is: all elements from one client are received first, then all elements from other task are received.
Why there are not different elements from different task mixed in the channel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Channels is a high-performance async-ready producer/consumer queue. The "high performance" bit means it will complete synchronously whenever possible.

> When socket client connects to server, server starts task for each client. Each client task is a producer for the channel.

This is fine. The first thing I'd check is whether each client is running on a separate *thread* (e.g., `Task.Run`), or if they're just async tasks.

> What happens is: all elements from one client are received first, then all elements from other task are received. Why there are not different elements from different task mixed in the channel?

I would expect a `WriteAsync` on an unbounded channel to always complete synchronously. Internally, it's just adding the item to a queue, and since the queue always has room (in an unbounded channel), there's nothing AFAIK that would make `WriteAsync` complete asynchronously. So the entire `foreach` loop in your produces runs synchronously.

There's nothing *wrong* with this behavior. If your producers are all running on different threads, then they may be running their `foreach` loops concurrently, and the elements may be interleaved. But each `foreach` loop will run *very* quickly, so it's likely that one thread will add all its items before another thread gets a chance.

Comment: Socket client task running on different thread. ManagedThreadId is different for each one.

Comment: Loop is quite big one and added Sleep(100) in the loop. was trying if other thread can get some room. Because in practical scenario, all clients must be able to add elements in the queue.